# How to keep the window focus on new Toplevel() window in Tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am currently writing a win32gui python27 application (I'm running win7). I am wondering if it is possible to create a new window from my mainloop() and KEEPING the focus on it, possibly by stopping the mainloop and deactivating the root window. In a sort of pseudo code example:

```
root=Tk()
#put in some widgets, such as statusbars, tkfileDialog widgets etc...
O=Toplevel()
OptionMenu(O) #wait for user to make his choices; btw: OptionMenu is a class...
tkFileDialog.askdirectory(...) #THEN interpret this line
```

Basically, I'd like to achieve what most of the widgets in tkfiledialog and tksimpledialog do:
To steal the focus from the main window (not just the console focus, the wm focus) and to resume the mainloop until AFTER everything in, for example, OptionMenu has been resolved. I hope I could make my goals clear to y'all, I just started Tkinter programming a couple of weeks ago and may confuse and misinterpret some concepts behind it....
That's all, folks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is called a "grab". Tkinter supports grabs with several methods. For example, to set a local grab on a toplevel you would do `my_window.grab_set()`. A local grab is where this window grabs the focus from all other windows in your app, but only for your app.

You can also do a global grab, which effectively freezes your entire display except for your specific window. This is very dangerous since you can easily lock yourself out of your own computer if you have a bug in your code.

Grabs do *not* deactivate the mainloop function. This must be running for your window to process events. It simply redirects all events to the window that has the grab.

For more information, read about grab_set and other grab commands here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.grab_set-method

Comment: My problem is clicking in `toplevel` covers up `top2` (a much smaller window). I tried: `self.top2.focus_force()` and `self.top2.grab_set()` but the thing that worked was: `self.top2.lift()`

Answer (score 2):

None of the above suggestions worked for me, on Mac OS El Capitan. But based on those hints, this does:

```
class Window(Tk.Toplevel):
    ...
    def setActive(self):
        self.lift()
        self.focus_force()
        self.grab_set()
        self.grab_release()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`grab.set()` is much to aggressive for my needs and blocks normal window operations. This answer is to make one Tkinter Window pop up overtop of other Tkinter windows.

In my app I have a large window `toplevel` which calls a much smaller window `top2` which initially appears on top of `toplevel`.

If user clicks within `toplevel` window it gains focus and smothers much smaller `top2` window until `toplevel` window is dragged off of it.

The solution is to click the button in `toplevel` to launch `top2` again. The `top2` open function knows it is already running so simply lifts it to the top and gives it focus:

```python
def play_items(self):
    ''' Play 1 or more songs in listbox.selection(). Define buttons:
            Close, Pause, Prev, Next, Commercial and Intermission
    '''

    if self.top2_is_active is True:
        self.top2.focus_force()     # Get focus
        self.top2.lift()            # Raise in stacking order
        root.update()
        return                      # Don't want to start playing again
```