# Setting tkinter to always be the current active window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use tkinter as a way to toggle an automation process. The snippet I have below works, but the hotkeys will only work when the tkinter window is the current active window.

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083491/make-a-tkinter-toplevel-active) discussing how this can be done, but these methods seem to be OS specific and none seem to work for Windows 10.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Automate(tk.Frame):

    __loop__ = None

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Automate, self).__init__(master)

        # F7 initiates the loop.
        self.master.bind('<F7>', lambda event: self.automate())
        # F8 stops the loop.
        self.master.bind('<F8>', lambda event: self.automate_cancel())
        # F9 closes the script.
        self.master.bind('<F9>', lambda event: self.master.quit())

    def automate(self):
        """Loops over this method."""
        print('Do Stuff')
        self.__loop__ = self.master.after(1, self.automate)

    def automate_cancel(self):
        """Exits loop and reset variable."""
        print('Stop Doing Stuff')
        self.master.after_cancel(self.__loop__)
        self.__loop__ = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Removes Window Border, minimize button, full screen button, and exit button.
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    # Forces window to always be on top.
    root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
    # Sets window as one pixel on the screen.
    root.geometry('0x0')

    Automate(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

In the script above, pressing `F7` initiates a script and loops it. `F8` stops the loop and `F9` exits the program completely. The keybinds only work when tkinter is the current active window. I would like for tkinter to read my keybinds without having to open the tkinter window.

Comment: If this is just for you and not going to be used by others then AutoHotKey might be worth trying out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7: how to bring a window to the front no matter what other window has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312627/windows-7-how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front-no-matter-what-other-window-has-fo)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter main window focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751100/tkinter-main-window-focus)