# Tkinter loses focus when Acrobat is opened using subprocess

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, focus, adobe

Writing an automated GUI to rename files by user input.

When I go to popopen the file in subprocess, the tkinter window loses focus, meaning I can't set focus on an entry.

I have tried time.sleep(), to see if I can give the GUI time to load. 
I have tried to force focus on the GUI.

```
def load(self):       
        if self.main_counter >= len(list_of_files):
            self.close()
            return

        filepath = list_of_files[self.main_counter]
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

        self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            [exts_to_index[ext.lower()]] + [filepath],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
            )

        root.title(filename)

        self.entries[0].focus_set()
```

I need the Tkinter window not to lose focus, and the 1st entry remains selected, when opening adobe alongside.

Comment: Take a look and see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944533/how-to-keep-the-window-focus-on-new-toplevel-window-in-tkinter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter main window focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751100/tkinter-main-window-focus)

Comment: @Roca I tried calling grab_set above my entry focus and Adobe is still taking focus.

Comment: @CommonSense I have said in the question I have tried force_focus and it didn't work. I review this specific question too. Thanks though.

Comment: Please, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47161643/6634373). As far as I know, there's no way to not lose focus for the first time.

Comment: Probably much more cumbersome than you anticipated, but you could get a module to hook into your OS to manipulate the focus on the OS level.  e.g. if you're on Windows, `pywinauto` is one option.