# How to make a tkinter window impossible to disappear by clicking outside of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want a tkinter window that isn't fullscreen. Normally, if I click outside of the window, the window will automatically go "underneath" the window I just clicked on. How can I make this window stay on the front of the screen, even when I click outside of it?

Comment: Maybe you need `root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep the window focus on new Toplevel() window in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944533/how-to-keep-the-window-focus-on-new-toplevel-window-in-tkinter)

Comment: @MeetTitan That isn't a duplicate because OP's questions is asking how to do it forever. The question you linked is similar, but not duplcate.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it to the top every second by using a loop that occurs every millisecond.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
def main_loop():
    window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
    window.focus()
    window.after(1, main_loop)
main_loop()
window.mainloop()
```